# using mysql in lua script

Tags: mysql, lua

I need to read a database table from inside a Lua script in pdns-recursor on a Scientific Linux 6.4 server which comes with Lua pre-loaded.

Apparently I have to use luarocks to install luasql.   When I attempt to install luasql I get:

```
Checking Lua includes... lua.h not found  
lua.h is not on the server.
```

I tried removing the installed version so I could install from binary but then that trashed the system which apparently uses the installed Lua for everything (yum, rpm, etc).  Now I have to reload OS.  How can I get MySQL access from embedded Lua?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your SQL lookup will block the pdns-recursor thread you are in (and by default, there are only two threads). You should strongly consider loading your data into memory and sticking to Lua table lookups.

Comment: oh no ... so I can't do a MySQL query from a pdns-recursor thread ?!?

Comment: I would not say "can't" but unless you have very patient users, you will need to configure many threads instead the default of '2', and this will cost memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have already checked yum to see if luasql is available through that; if not, you should first do that, and install it through yum if possible.

The immediate cause of the problem you're having is that luarocks automatically builds modules from source, which requires access to the lua headers. These are not needed simply to *run* programs that use Lua, so they are not installed as part of the normal Lua package. I'm not familiar with Scientific Linux, but you can probably get them by installing a package named `lua-dev`, `lua-devel`, `lua-headers`, or some variant thereof. You may also need the mySQL packages (both the libraries proper and the headers). Once you have those installed, give it another try.

You might also try [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/), which I find to be generally more polished than luarocks, and capable of automatically downloading more dependencies; in particular it probably will not require the lua headers installed, and can handle automatically downloading and installing lua itself from source. It does, however, require CMake installed.

If for some reason you can't install the required headers and can't get luarocks *or* luadist working, you can try downloading and building luaSQL by hand. The Lua headers can be found in the Lua 5.1 source package and [LuaSQL 2.2](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/#download). Assuming the Scientific Linux maintainers haven't excessively customized the version of lua they ship with it, the results should be compatible with the system Lua install.

Comment: Thanks ... you were right.  I did check yum first and did not find anything because I didn't have all of the repositories loaded ... after loading the repositories I found it and installed it.